# Can not execute "Hello, World!" C program with user other than 'root'

Tags: permissions, filesystems, gcc, yocto

I have written a ["Hello, World!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) C file `myCFile.c` on an x86 embedded board on the Debian OS.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello\n")
}
```

I compile the program: `gcc myCFile.c`

However,

```
tester@localhost:~/test$ ./a.out
-bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
tester@localhost:~/pravin$ ls -lrt
total 44
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tester test   54 Sep  7 07:33 myCFile.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tester test   16608 Sep  7 07:33 a.out
```

However, if I copy `a.out` to `/run/user/1000`, I can execute it.

```
tester@localhost:/run/user/1000$ ls
a.out  bus  gnupg  systemd
```

Also, I can execute it when I compile the C file with root user and execute it. I can execute it.

```
root@localhost:~# gcc myCFile.c
root@localhost:~# ./a.out
hello
root@localhost:~#
```

Is it something related to the `NOEXEC` flag?

My `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# Begin /etc/fstab
/dev/root    /        ext4        defaults        0    0 proc
/proc        proc        nosuid,noexec,nodev    0    0 sysfs        /sys        sysfs        nosuid,noexec,nodev    0    0 devpts
/dev/pts    devpts        gid=5,mode=620        0    0 tmpfs
/run        tmpfs        defaults,size=1500M    0    0 devtmpfs
/dev        devtmpfs    mode=0755,nosuid    0    0
# End /etc/fstab
LABEL=persistent    /persistent    ext4    defaults,data=journal,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec    0    2
/persistent/home    /home    none    defaults,bind    0    0
/persistent/tmp    /tmp    none    defaults,bind    0    0
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with *"yocto"*?

Comment: Does it really contain the misspelling *"#inlcude"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen most likely not, the CPP would have complained. I edited that one out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is it something related NOEXEC flag?

Yes; presumably `/home` is mounted `noexec`, which means you can’t run binaries there. `/tmp/user/1000` works because it’s a on different file system, as is `/root` (`root`’s home directory).

In your case,

```
mount -o remount,exec /persistent
```

should allow you to execute files in your home directory.

Comment: Huh, having noexec `/home` but not noexec `/run/user` seems like a security flaw :)

Comment: @hobbs why? unless you prevent any processes from mmaping executable pages (as e.g. recent versions of android do), mounting any tmpfs noexec is purely self-congratulatory feel-good posturing security theater. You don't even need mmap or constructing your executable by hand -- you can just copy any binary into a memfd file and then executing it via `pexecve` or `execveat`

Comment: @UncleBilly well, then there's no longer any point to noexec anything, is there?

Comment: @Joshua Isn't that the purpose of the `nosuid` mount option?

Comment: The point of `noexec` isn't to get around a determined user, it's to prevent a trojan horse on removable media. @hobbs

Comment: @Barmar In several decades that's mostly not how I've seen it used, and it's not what it's being used for here. But oh well :)

Comment: @Barmar `/home` would be a very strange place to mount removable media to :)